# Duda sobre nombrar los proyectos en Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Necesito poner un nombre determinado a un proyecto en Eclipse(es mi TFG), anteriormente lo he creado pero lo borré debido a que estaba mal, entonces quería volver a crearlo y al poner el nombre, me salta un mensaje de información diciendo que usará la configuración del JRE del anterior, cosa que no debe suceder, ya que tengo que usar una posterior.

Al borrar un proyecto queda guardado algún fichero en algún lugar del workspace o de los directorios de Eclipse que me limitan con el nombre?

Comment: ¿Lo eliminaste solamente de eclipse? ó ¿fuiste al path fisico?

Comment: Intentaste buscar en el buscador el nombre del proyecto , haber si esta por algun lado ?

Comment: @Villegas lo eliminé desde eclipse solo.

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag lo busqué y no aparece nada.